# Hadoop/Yarn Docker-Container-Executor fails because of "Invalid docker rw mount"

Tags: docker, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to execute the simple example for the Hadoop/Yarn (Version: 2.9.1) Docker-Container-Executor:

```
vars="YARN_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_TYPE=docker,YARN_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_DOCKER_IMAGE=hadoop-docker"
hadoop jar hadoop-examples.jar pi -Dyarn.app.mapreduce.am.env=$vars -Dmapreduce.map.env=$vars -Dmapreduce.reduce.env=$vars 10 100
```

Unfortunately the job fails with the following exception:

```
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: [2018-09-08 22:23:54.288]Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1536441225683_0004_02_000001
Exit code: 29
Exception message: Invalid docker rw mount '/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1536441225683_0004/:/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1536441225683_0004/', realpath=/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/nm-local-dir/usercache/hadoop/appcache/application_1536441225683_0004/
Error constructing docker command, docker error code=14, error message='Invalid docker read-write mount'
```

Anybody has an idea how to solve the **Invalid docker read-write mount**?

Answer (score 2):

Solved by adding this directory to property **docker.allowed.rw-mounts** in **etc/hadoop/container-executor.cfg**. If you get error message for multiple directories they need to be added comma seperated.

In my case:

```
docker.allowed.rw-mounts=/usr/local/hadoop/,/var/hadoop/yarn/local-dir,/var/hadoop/yarn/log-dir,/tmp/hadoop-hadoop/
```